# Oracle 11g preference does not exist: CTXSYS.AUTO_FILTER

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g

Getting the following error for creating a Index that uses CTXSYS.AUTO_FILTER.

```
ORA-20000: Oracle Text error:
DRG-10700: preference does not exist: CTXSYS.AUTO_FILTER
ORA-06512: at "CTXSYS.DRUE", line 160
ORA-06512: at "CTXSYS.TEXTINDEXMETHODS", line 366
```

I guess need to run some script which can re-create the CTXSYS.AUTO_FILTER preference. 
Which script to run ? Using oracle 11g

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check first

```
SELECT *
FROM CTXSYS.CTX_PREFERENCES
```

and then if necessary:

```
ctx_ddl.create_preference('AUTO_FILTER', 'AUTO_FILTER');
```

Answer (score 2):

Or more automated:

```
declare
  filter_count number;
begin
select count(*) into filter_count FROM CTXSYS.CTX_PREFERENCES WHERE PRE_NAME = 'AUTO_FILTER';
IF  filter_count = 0 THEN
   ctx_ddl.create_preference('AUTO_FILTER', 'AUTO_FILTER');
END IF;
end;
/
```